# HttpsURLConnection 400 Bad Request error occured

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, firebase

I need to convert below Swift code to Java.
Swift code works.
But, Java code is not worked.

HttpsURLConnection has failed.

responseCode: 400 (HttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode())

message2: Bad Request (HttpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage())

How can I solve 400 Bad Request error.

In Swift(It worked)

```
func sendNotification(token: String, message: String) {

 //Firebase CloudMessaging serverkey
    var firebaseServerKey = "AAAAA6qLps4:APA91bE7szGAgp3qYGOJsrSsrM1InhIgf5Fq1xxxxxx"

    let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.setValue("key=\(firebaseServerKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = "{\"to\":\"\(token)\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"\(message)\",\"badge\":\"1\"}}".data(using: .utf8)

}
```

I wrote in JAVA(not worked)

```
private void sendNotification(String token, String message) {
//Firebase CloudMessaging serverkey
    var firebaseServerKey = "AAAAA6qLps4:APA91bE7szGAgp3qYGOJsrSsrM1InhIgf5Fq1xxxxxx"

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+firebaseServerKey);


        String str = "{\"to\": " + token + ", \"notification\": { \"body\": " + message + ", \"badge\": \"1\"}}";


        byte[] outputInBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(outputInBytes);
        os.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode(); // responseCode: 400

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("Success", String.valueOf(responseCode));
        } else {
            String code = String.valueOf(responseCode);
            String message2 = conn.getResponseMessage(); // message2: Bad Request
            Log.d("Fail", String.valueOf(responseCode));
            Log.d("Fail2", conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON request body is incorrect. It produce `{"to": zxc}` which is an invalid json. Change it to

```
String str = "{\"to\": \"" + token + "\", \"notification\": { \"body\": \"" +
    message + "\", \"badge\": \"1\"}}";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I could not build sucess with your code. Im not familiar to Json things. How Should I change it?

Comment: Hi, I still have failed build like below image.

Comment: There i updated it. i checked in my IDE. misplaced again sorry